# Python - allowed values of a variable

Tags: python, enums

How can I explicitly define what values can given variable have? Let's say I want value of variable **size** to be either **'small'**, **'medium'**, or **'big'** and nothing else.

EDIT:
I want to avoid a situation when variable is set to something from beyond the list (for example to 'tiny' in this case). Like enum in Java. This variable would be a class field.

Comment: Define for what, or whom? Docstrings, enumerators, constants, assertions, validations or any combination could be useful. What have you got now, and what precisely is the problem with it?

Comment: Each variable already has a specific type. You `size` variable would be type string, unless `small`, `medium`, and `large` are variables that are assigned to integers. Please clarify your question though, because as of now, it is **very** ambiguous .

Comment: ve @JakeBut: Please give some example on what you are trying to achieve. Your requirement is not clear

Comment: I want to avoid a situation when variable is set to something from beyond the list (for example to **'tiny'** in this case). Like enum in Java. This variable would be a class field.

Comment: You could try finding a programming language where this is possible.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Simplest way would be to always use dedicated method which would firstly validate input and if it's correct then set variable. Below you may find some example:

```py
class Test:
   def __init__(self):
      self.__variable = None

   def set_variable(self, value):
      if value not in ('small', 'medium', 'big'):
         raise ValueError()
      self.__variable = value
```

Comment: He never said that he wanted to use strings for small, medium, and large. You should just avoid answer questions like this one, because they are very broad and ambiguous.

Comment: @MoinuddinQuadri How do you know this? Did he tell you already?

Comment: @Mr.goosberry I do not know this, that is why I haven't answered anything. It is based on my assumption of variable name i.e. `size`

Comment: @MoinuddinQuadri well it sounded like you were trying to correct someone, and state it as fact. If you don't know, then why are you trying to correct someone else? **They** may be right, and in this case they probably are.

Comment: @Mr.goosberry I think you are right. I just commented based on what I was thinking ignoring the ambiguity with the question.

Comment: @MoinuddinQuadri thanks for agreeing, and not getting angry. And like I said above, these type of questions really can't be answered. We can take all the guess we want, but until the OP clarifies the question, we can't give a good solid answer.

Comment: @Mr.goosberry Quote characters indicate strings, no?

Comment: @StefanPochmann Well that is very much plausible, but he could be trying to use the quotes as a way to highlight his variable values in his question post. And as I said above, we really don't know unless he clarifies his question.

Comment: Actually this solution would work in my case. As to variable type in the example, indeed I was thinking of strings (hence quotes).

Comment: @Mr.goosberry I did post this answer as for me it was not ambiguous due to usage of quotes. It would be suspicious if only words were bold but quotes were bold as well. Just in my defense.

Comment: @Yakuza Well it appears that you guessed right. But I only like to answer questions that I know can be concretely answered, and I don't have to  guess about what the OP means.

Answer (score 5):

You are describing an `enumeration`, which is supported in Python by the `enum` library:

```
from enum import Enum

class Size(Enum):
    small = 'small'
    medium = 'medium'
    big = 'big'

size = Size('big')
print(size)
try:
    size = Size('tiny')
except ValueError as e:
    print("invalid Size (", e.args[0].split()[0],
          "). Size must be one of 'small', 'medium' or 'big'", sep='')
```

**Output:**

```
Size.big
invalid Size ('tiny'). Size must be one of 'small', 'medium' or 'big'
```

Comment: Can't you set `size = 'tiny'`?

Comment: yes but it would be a `str`. Given Python's duck typing you can set any variable to anything, so there is no formulation that would prevent such an assignment.

Comment: The question asks `How can I explicitly define what values can [a] given variable have?`. While enums are relevant, it doesn't seem like you can restrict in Python a general variable to have a limited set of values. Class fields are another matter.

Comment: In a strict sense you are correct, but in practice the use case OP describes is best handled in Python by the `enum` library. Even if you make `size` an instance of a class that restricts instance variable values (which is actually what you are doing by using `enum`, just doing it Pythonically), you can again just do `size = 'tiny'` and shed `size's` `enumity`

Answer (score 3):

You could define a Size class inside your class and then set the size attribute while checking whether the value is allowed. Below a minimal example:

```
from enum import Enum

class Trial:
    class Size(Enum):
        small = "small"
        medium = "medium"
        large = "large"

    def __init__(self, size):
        self._set_size(size)
 
    def _set_size(self, size):
        if size in set(item.value for item in self.Size):
            self._size = size
        else:
            raise ValueError("size value not valid")
```